# Android GPS app not closing connection

Tags: android, process, gps, shutdown

Fairly new to Android, so just trying to work out:

I have a simple Maps app that plots a couple of locations. It's a demo for a potentially bigger app later. The one thing I would like to do is make it exit correctly. I want to assume that when a user hits the "Home" or "Back" button on the phone, that they have exited the app. I want when this has happened for the GPS process to shut down. I can't seem to find any examples of how to do this correctly. I have an onDestroy() subclass with a super.onDestroy() method but this doesn't seem to cut it. I've tested on my phone and while everything else seems to work fine, this is bugging me. I keep seeing the GPS icon in the notifications bar. To give you an example, this doesn't happen when you leave GoogleMaps.

Anyone any ideas or know what I'm missing?

T

Answer (score 1):

When an activity is no longer visible to the user its `onStop()` callback will be called. What you can do is call `finish()` to end the activity at that point.

Comment: That's great, thanks a million JRL. It's still not exactly as I'd like, so I'm going to put button listeners in to it too. But this solves the main issue I was having.

Always so simple. Thanks again.